# viewWillDisappear method of a UIViewPopover with navigationController

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am developing an application that shows a popover. This popover contains two views with a navigationController. 
This is the navigation hierarchy:

```
--(row)-->   PopoverView1   --(barButton)-->   PopoverView2
```

I want to save the data contained in PopoverView1 also when I tap outside of the popover. The problem is that when I navigate to PopoverView2, the viewWillDisappear is called too and the popover dismiss.

Thanks and sorry for my english ;)

Comment: are you did anything in the viewWillDisappear?

Comment: yes, I have a method that save the data when tap the "Done" button and also I call this method from viewWillDisappear

Comment: you have bar button right after pressing the bar button u can save ...

Comment: why you call the view will appear method... i think i miss understood can u say what you are doing in the bar button press and view will appear...

Comment: I am not calling the viewWillAppear method, I call another method from viewWillAppear. I want to save data when I tap the button and also when I tap outside the popover. I have tried to implement the another method (the metod that save the data) inside viewWillAppear, but the problem is that when I navigate to the second view of the popover, the viewWillDisappear of the first popover is called automatically so I can't access to the second popover view.

Comment: you need to create the custom local method to dismiss the popover and that method contains your save code and this line to dismiss the popover [_popoverObject dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];   and also refer this [link] http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial